# Does Passive Sign Convention not have to follow a loop?

Tags: circuit-analysis

In my introductory circuits class, we are learning about passive sign convention and basic circuit analysis, but my professor made a drawing showing the current going into the signs in a way that if the current followed the loop, it seems as though passive sign convention would be broken for at least one of the branches. What am I missing here? Thanks! [image: passive sign convention loop]

Comment: This looks like both KCL and KVL are being discussed in the same set of scribbles there. The passive sign convention (for passive components) is that the current direction is from the more positive terminal to the more negative terminal. Or, that you assign the (+) and (-) such that this is the case if you are already given the current direction. Personally, I don't sweat any of it. I just go with whatever. The math gets the same semantic results, regardless. What's the issue, exactly? You don't like it that the KVL loop current points oppositely to I1? I=-I1. Seems okay to me.

Comment: A reason for a passive sign convention is that if the voltage across the device is always positive (subtracting the voltage at the negative end from the more positive end means it always yields a positive result) and if the passive sign convention current is positive, too, then the device *dissipates* power.  If the passive sign convention current is negative, then the device *supplies* power. There are four ways you can arrange the combined directions of I1 and I2 and two ways you can arrange the loop current, clockwise and counterclockwise. All produce the same semantics when you also think.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Cool! Just realize that *conventions* are ***human** conventions*. Nature doesn't care about what we think about the world. It does what it does. It's ***our*** job to acquire useful simplifying ideas that allow us to understand enough of just some small part of it to be ***sometimes useful***. Nature also doesn't care how a teacher thinks nor does it care what a teacher imagines is important. You may want a good grade. But nature doesn't care about that. Your only hope is that what the teacher wants from you to get a good grade is also ***sometimes useful***. ;)